# How do I find Google Ads Script method names?

Tags: google-ads-script

I am just starting to learn Google Ads Scripting. I found an example in google how to Export Google Ads Data to Google Sheets using Scripts, but have a problem to specify my columns.

Step 2 of the code have all the columns that I need to pull. Now I need to specify their Method names in Step4 and in Step3 change 'Campaign Type' (column) to right name from Google Ads report.

Where should I look at this? Thanks for your advice!

So starter code looks like this:

```
function main() {
 
  //Step 1: Connect Google Ads to the Google Sheet
  var spreadsheetUrl = 'link here';
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl);
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  ss.clear();
 
  //Step 2: Create an array to store the data
  var sheetarray = [['Day', 'Account', 'Customer ID', 'Campaign', 'Ad Group', 'Campaign Type', 'Campaign Subtype', 'Image ad name', 'Currency', 'Clicks', 'Impressions', 'Cost', 'Conversions', 'Video-through conv.', 'Video played to 25%', 'Video played to 50%', 'Video played to 75%', 'Video played to 100%', 'Views']];
 
  //Step 3: Collect the data you need from Google Ads
  var keywords = AdsApp.keywords()
      .withCondition("Campaign Type = 'Video'")
      .forDateRange("LAST_30_DAYS")
      .get();
 
  //Step 4: Add the data you got from Google Ads into the array
  while (keywords.hasNext()) {
    var keyword = keywords.next();
    sheetarray.push([
        keyword.getText(),
        keyword.getStatsFor("LAST_30_DAYS").getClicks(),
        keyword.getStatsFor("LAST_30_DAYS").getConversions()
      ]);
  }
   
  //Step 5: Display the contents of the array
  Logger.log(sheetarray);
 
  if (sheetarray.length > 0) {
     
    // Step 6: Send the array's data to the Google Sheet
    ss.getRange(1, 1, sheetarray.length, sheetarray[0].length).setValues(sheetarray);
     
    // Step 7: Send email with link to Google Sheet
    MailApp.sendEmail("a@gmail.com", "Keywords with 'Video' Campaign Type", "Here's the link: "+spreadsheetUrl);
  }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use appendRow

```
ss.appendRow(sheetarray);
```